# How to determine mode for a number of date values and what to do when there is more than one mode

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with each row representing an email open event by a user. I want to determine the mode of all open events per user to return the most common hour of the day the user opens an email. If there is no mode I want to output the last hour of the day the user opened an email, if there is more than one mode I want to output the one with the most recent open event.

The result I want is a table with each row representing a userid and the optimal hour of the day to send to them.

I have been able to determine the mode per user and output this, with help from another post, but I am unable to figure out the clauses for when there is no mode and when there is more than one mode. Here is the SQLFiddle with the test data and the query I have so far: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d4276/4

Expected result table from the fiddle above:

[image]

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what would be the expected results based off the fiddle?

Comment: Only one row per subscriberkey, currently since subscriber key '6078' has two modes they appear as two rows.

Comment: what are the `modes` here? and as @scsimon said you should include the expected output as part of your question so we have something to compare.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza In the example fiddle the modes are 8 and 10 for subscriber 6078, since there are two I would like to only take the mode with the most recent event date which is 8 in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the code that you want:

```
SELECT SubscriberKey, Hour
FROM (SELECT SubscriberKey, DATEPART(hour, EventDate) as hour, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SubscriberKey
                                ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, MAX(EventDate) DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM OpenJobs oj
      GROUP BY SubscriberKey, DATEPART(hour, EventDate)
    ) sh
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

The `MAX(EventDate)` in the `ORDER BY` gets the latest hour in the event of ties.

You don't have to worry about "no mode".  All data has a mode, although there could be a bunch of ties.  The above code returns the most recent hour in the event of ties.  I think the key to the solution is using `row_number()` (which never has ties) instead of `rank()` (which does have ties).

Comment: why you have `cnt` for?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . Because I would want to see it in the result set, even if the OP doesn't want to see it.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! In my original fiddle I used Alter Table to change eventdate to hour only, is there a more efficient way to do this without using alter table?

Comment: @cmccarra . . . I don't see an advantage to adding an `hour` column, unless you were going to add an index on `(SubscriberKey, hour)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The end goal is to feed this back into my email sending platform and send out emails in batches based on the hour, so all users with hour value 15 automatically send at 3pm etc.

Comment: @cmccarra . . . I mean, the result set contains the hour.  You don't need to modify the table itself.